# How do I convert a web-scraped table into a csv?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

A year ago I learned some python in one of my classes but haven't had to use much since then so this may or may not be a simple question.

I'm trying to web-scrape the top grossing films of all time table from Box Office Mojo and I want to grab the rank, title, and gross for the top 10 films in the 2010s. I've been playing around in python and I can get the entire table into python but I don't know how to manipulate it from there, let alone write out a csv file. Any guidance/tips?

Here is what will print the entire table for me (the first few lines are copied from an old web-scraping assignment to get me started):

```
    import bs4
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

    url = "https://www.boxofficemojo.com/chart/top_lifetime_gross/"
    headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
     like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}
    page_html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    page_soup = soup(page_html.text, "html.parser")

    boxofficemojo_table = page_soup.find("div", {"class": "a-section imdb-scroll-table-inner"})
    complete_table = boxofficemojo_table.get_text()
    print(complete_table)`
```

Comment: What have you tried to write to CSV per row in table? Or maybe look into openpyxl or another excel writer.

Comment: _I can get the entire table into python_ Into Python as what?

Comment: Your code returns a long string. I was able to clean it up a bit using `.get_text(separator=' ')` but I think you will want to split it into a dict based on some criteria. It looks like you can ID the `:` and then check characters before that for a number to get your key and everything after the `:` as value but that may take some complex logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can use pd.read_html for this.

```
import pandas as pd

Data = pd.read_html(r'https://www.boxofficemojo.com/chart/top_lifetime_gross/')
for data in Data:
    data.to_csv('Data.csv', ',')
```

---

2.Using Bs4

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = r'https://www.boxofficemojo.com/chart/top_lifetime_gross/'
print('\n>> Exctracting Data using Beautiful Soup for :'+ URL)

try:
    res = requests.get(URL)
except Exception as e:
    print(repr(e))

print('\n<> URL present status Code = ',(res.status_code))
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
table = soup.find('table')

list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll(["td"]):
        text = cell.text
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

for item in list_of_rows:
    ' '.join(item)

Data = pd.DataFrame(list_of_rows)
Data.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all',inplace = True)
print(Data.head(10))

Data.to_csv('Table.csv')
```

Comment: This is so great, thank you! The only question I have is how to only pull the top 10 from the 2010s at the end. Would it be an "if/then" statement nested under the "for cell in row.findAll(["td"])?

Comment: You can do that with pandas with iloc function on the DataFrame